# Django handling request

Tags: python, django, server

I want to know if django creates a new instance of the view (or the whole app) on each request.

Im not sure if this fit too but would love to know if a request will have to wait for a current one to complete before the incoming starts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you elaborate a little please

Comment: It depends on your wsgi server. Typically you will have several worker processes to handle incoming requests in parallell. But slow view functions can be a bottleneck and keep all the wsgi workers busy.

Comment: @HåkenLid does the parallel workers wait on each other to run through the view or they do that in parallel

Comment: They don't block each other from executing the same code, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if django creates a new instance of the view (or the whole app) on each request.

Nope - unless you serve your project with plain cgi of course but that would be a very very strange choice.

> Im not sure if this fit too but would love to know if a request will have to wait for a current one to complete before the incoming starts?

Depends on how many worker processes / threads you use to serve your project. A single worker process/thread will handle a single request at a time obviously.

Comment: on the second part... suppose there r 3 worker threads, will they all use the view simultaneously or will have to wait on the current one using it?

Comment: They of course will work in parallel - that's the point of having a multiprocess or multithreaded server actually.

Answer (score 1):

No it usually does not. Please refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/ for a detailed explanation.